# Handling scroll bars in VC++ 6.0 and MFC

Tags: visual-c++, scrollbar, visual-c++-6

Hai in vc++6.0 MFC, i connected a serial port, while reading and displaying a data(i want to display date and time ) in edit box (IDC_EDIT1),

My problem is I used a vertical scrollbar in the edit box.
Whenever I display new data, the vertical scrollbar moves up; it must come down (scroll down),

The written code:

```
CString temp;
    static CString dat;
    static CString tim;

    if (dat != m_date || tim != m_time)
    {
        temp = "\r\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n";
        temp = temp + "Date: ";
        temp = temp + m_date;
        temp = temp + "\t\t\t";
        temp = temp + "Time: ";
        temp = temp + m_time;
        temp = temp + "\r\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    }

    dat = m_date;
    tim = m_time;

    temp = temp + "\r\n\r\n";
    temp = temp + m_sensorname +"\t\t";
    temp = temp + m_value + "\t\t";
    temp = temp + m_units;

    if (m_datalog_id ==0x01)
        m_pdialog->m_editlog1= m_pdialog->m_editlog1 + temp;
    else if(m_datalog_id==0x02)
        m_pdialog->m_editlog2 = m_pdialog->m_editlog2 + temp;
    else
        return;

    m_pdialog->UpdateData(false);
```

Comment: Please edit and change the title to something more on-topic.  "I need help!" is a terrible title.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow too, and do check the faq to avoid getting downvoted in the future.

Comment: Please use descriptive titles and proper English. I understand that English isn't everyone's first language, but this is just careless.

Comment: @Rahul: you should read: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html - your question as posed was not paying much heed to the precepts therein.

Comment: @Draemon -- You're assuming that the poster's level of English ability is above the level of this post. It's possible that he was anything but careless and spent hours composing this to the best of his ability.

Comment: @Draemon - Please simply edit the text to be more grammatically correct, and refrain from public judgements about his character. Obviously this can be a better post, and is not in accordance with posting guidelines. Perhaps he can't read English well enough to understand the guidelines in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you write your text to the edit control, call `IDC_EDIT1.ScrollToCaret()`. That will scroll it down to the bottom where the new line is.